# meteor app deployed to heroku successfully. heroku errors when I goes to the url

Tags: meteor, heroku

These are the error logs:

Heroku local runs perfectly fine. Does anyone know what these error logs mean and what I need to do to fix it?

Thank you.

I changed the node version to 0.10.45 since I hear that's what heroku needs to run meteor apps.

Things changed but I am getting an npm error now. I believe the npm version is 2.1+.

Please note since I do not use a mongo db in the app I did NOT include a mongo:labs setting in the heroku config. Does this break things as well?

```
   2016-06-13T03:56:13.082236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085838+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-13T03:56:13.861094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-13T03:56:15.460115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=keela.herokuapp.com request_id=eb256901-593c-43a0-be3e-e4347daecf40 fwd="206.108.215.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082494+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls keela
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085156+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.861094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-13T03:56:13.846631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T03:56:15.460115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=keela.herokuapp.com request_id=eb256901-593c-43a0-be3e-e4347daecf40 fwd="206.108.215.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-13T03:56:13.846631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T03:56:15.460115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=keela.herokuapp.com request_id=eb256901-593c-43a0-be3e-e4347daecf40 fwd="206.108.215.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082494+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls keela
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085156+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082702+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085838+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-13T03:56:13.846631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T03:56:16.056881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=keela.herokuapp.com request_id=45e1c2db-39c7-427f-b115-5a5927267642 fwd="206.108.215.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082494+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls keela
2016-06-13T03:56:13.082702+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-06-13T03:56:13.085838+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-13T03:56:13.861094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-13T03:56:13.846631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T03:56:15.460115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=keela.herokuapp.com request_id=eb256901-593c-43a0-be3e-e4347daecf40 fwd="206.108.215.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

These are the heroku logs from terminal:

```
2016-06-13T03:56:05.528129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-13T03:56:06.563040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-06-13T03:56:08.477065+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.477075+00:00 app[web.1]: > keela@ start /app
2016-06-13T03:56:08.477108+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2016-06-13T03:56:08.477109+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.480791+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2016-06-13T03:56:08.484354+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.488227+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
2016-06-13T03:56:08.488707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-06-13T03:56:08.488728+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v0.10.45
2016-06-13T03:56:08.488892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489134+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489268+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489490+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! keela@ start: `meteor run`
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489846+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-06-13T03:56:08.489945+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the keela@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490119+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the keela package,
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490220+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490622+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490726+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs keela
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490821+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490919+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-06-13T03:56:08.490999+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls keela
2016-06-13T03:56:08.491174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-06-13T03:56:08.493551+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.493856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-06-13T03:56:08.494156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-06-13T03:56:09.185720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-13T03:56:09.186797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-13T03:56:09.168263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T03:56:10.415088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
```

Comment: It might be because of an incompatible Node.js version, Meteor still uses 0.10.x and you use 5.x. A nice way to solve this is using Docker. Check out https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord

Comment: Which build pack do you use?

Comment: The build pack I used was this one: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor

Thanks I"ll look at docker.... is there another way?

Comment: I changed the version of node to 0.10.45 and it is still broken. but I have new errors now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buildpacks or meteor heroku are still very unstable.
I had to go through comments of a buildpack site to use a fork of a buildpack.

You are also correct that meteor still uses 0.10.41+ version of node.
I changed this by changing my version of node to 0.10.45 using nvm.

Also using a npm version of 2.1.1

Make sure to configure your package.json for these settings as well!

Heroku error logs are so vague it gives me headaches.